# Python: How to prevent Scipy's optimize.minimize function from changing the shape of initial guess x0?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to implement the optimization algorithm from Scipy. It works fine when I implement it without inputting the Jacobian gradient function. I believe the issue that I am getting when I input the gradient is because the minimize function itself is changing the shape of the initial guess x0. You can see this from the output of the code below.

Input:

```
import numpy as np
from costFunction import *
import scipy.optimize as op

def sigmoid(z):

    epsilon = np.finfo(z.dtype).eps

    g = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    g = np.clip(g,epsilon,1-epsilon)
    return g

def costFunction(theta,X,y):
    m = y.size
    h = sigmoid(X@theta)
    J = 1/(m)*(-y.T@np.log(h)-(1-y).T@np.log(1-h))
    grad = 1/m*X.T@(h-y)
    print ('Shape of theta is',np.shape(theta),'\n')
    print ('Shape of gradient is',np.shape(grad),'\n')
    return J, grad

X = np.array([[1, 3],[5,7]])
y = np.array([[1],[0]])

m,n = np.shape(X)
one_vec = np.ones((m,1))
X = np.hstack((one_vec,X))
initial_theta = np.zeros((n+1,1))

print ('Running costFunction before executing minimize function...\n')
cost, grad = costFunction(initial_theta,X,y) #To test the shape of gradient before calling minimize

print ('Executing minimize function...\n')
Result = op.minimize(costFunction,initial_theta,args=(X,y),method='TNC',jac=True,options={'maxiter':400})
```

Output:

```
Running costFunction before executing minimize function...

Shape of theta is (3, 1) 
Traceback (most recent call last):

Shape of gradient is (3, 1) 

Executing minimize function...

Shape of theta is (3,) 

  File "C:/Users/#####/minimizeshapechange.py", line 34, in <module>
Shape of gradient is (3, 2) 

    Result = op.minimize(costFunction,initial_theta,args=(X,y),method='TNC',jac=True,options={'maxiter':400})
  File "C:\Users\#####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 453, in minimize
    **options)
  File "C:\Users\#####\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\tnc.py", line 409, in _minimize_tnc
    xtol, pgtol, rescale, callback)
ValueError: tnc: invalid gradient vector from minimized function.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I will not analyze your exact computations, but some remarks:

- (1) Your gradient is broken!

  - scipy expects a [partial derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) resulting in an array of shape equal to your `x0`.
  - your gradient is of shape `(3,2)`, while `(n+1, 1)` is expected
  - compare with the example given in the tutorial which uses `scipy.optimize.rosen_der` (der = derivative)
- (2) It seems your scipy-version is a bit older, because mine (0.19.0) is telling me:

  - `ValueError: tnc: invalid gradient vector from minimized function.`

Some supporting source-code from [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/2526df72e5d4ca8bad6e2f4b3cbdfbc33e805865/scipy/optimize/tnc/moduleTNC.c#L96):

```
if (PyArray_SIZE(arr_grad) != py_state->n)
{
  PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
    "tnc: invalid gradient vector from minimized function.");
  goto failure;
```

**Remark:** This code above was changed / touched / introduced 5 years ago. If you really don't get this error while using your code listed (with removal of the import of costFunction), it seems you are using scipy < v0.13.0b1, which i do no recommend! I assume you are using some deprecated windows-based inofficial distribution with outdated scipy. You should change that!

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.

1. The reason the gradient is (3,2) is because the minimize function is changing it. I have edited the code to include a print statement before calling the minimize function to demonstrate this.

2. I am not sure about the issue with the version since mine is 0.19.0 as well and am getting the same output as you.

Comment: You should have mentioned that error. Well... then be more careful with those shapes. Usually the initial vector is of shape ```(n,)``` (which is not exactly ```(n, 1)```), and in this case, minimize does not change anything and your gradient is still broken. (```Shape of theta before executing optimization function: (3,) ... Shape of theta inside costFunction is (3,) ... grad:  [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.]]```)

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I have updated the code once more. I have input print statement for shape of theta and gradient before and after executing the minimization function. As you can see, they both change from (3,1) to (3,).

Comment: I already told you: start with ```initial_theta = np.zeros(n+1)``` and see (which is in my opinion the correct shape; although i can't guarantee that's the only working approach; at least minimize is not changing anything then which is to be expected!).

Comment: So, what you're saying is I should have the input theta as 1D vectors and inside the costFunction to resize the theta to a 2D column vector in order to do the linear algebra?

Comment: I'm saying: (1) I only know the flat ```(x,)``` input-approach. (2) Using this approach, scipy is not modifying shapes (3) Without scipy modifying shapes, your gradient is still wrong. So do whatever you need to calculate it; you can reshape or use broadcasting or do just anything, but the output should be flat too and of correct size (equal to x). (4) When you modified your gradient-calculation, i recommend checking it with [optimize.check_grad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html#scipy.optimize.check_grad).

Comment: All right. Thank you very much for your time and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Scipy trying to do the same thing as you. I don't  understand exactly why this solves the problem but playing with array shapes until it worked gave me the following:

#### Gradient function defined as follows

```
def Gradient(theta,X,y):
    #Initializing variables
    m = len(y)
    theta = theta[:,np.newaxis]     #<---- THIS IS THE TRICK
    grad = np.zeros(theta.shape)

    #Vectorized computations
    z = X @ theta
    h = sigmoid(z)
    grad = (1/m)*(X.T @ ( h - y));

    return grad    #< --- also works with grad.ravel()
```

#### Initial_theta initialized as

```
initial_theta = np.zeros((n+1))
initial_theta.shape
```

(3,)

i.e. a simple numpy array rather than a column vector.

#### Gradient function returns

```
Gradient(initial_theta,X,y).shape
```

(3,1) or (3,) depending on whether the function returns `grad` or `grad.ravel`

#### scipy.optimize called as

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
model = opt.minimize(fun = CostFunc, x0 = initial_theta, args = (X, y), method = 'TNC', jac = Gradient)
```

#### What does not work with Scipy

initial_theta of shape (3,1) using `initial_theta = np.zeros((n+1))[:,np.newaxis]` crashes the scipy.minimize function call.

> ValueError: tnc: invalid gradient vector from minimized function.

If someone could clarify these points that would be great ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

your code of costFunctuion is wrong,maybe you should look that

```
def costFunction(theta,X,y):
   h_theta = sigmoid(X@theta)
   J = (-y) * np.log(h_theta) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h_theta)
return np.mean(J)
```

Answer (score 0):

please copy and past in jpuiter in1 and so on in separte cell

```
In 1
                        import pandas as pd
                        import numpy as np
                        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
                        import seaborn as sns
                        %matplotlib inline
                        filepath =('C:/Pythontry/MachineLearning/dataset/couresra/ex2data1.txt')
                        data =pd.read_csv(filepath,sep=',',header=None)
                        #print(data)
                        X = data.values[:,:2]  #(100,2)
                        y = data.values[:,2:3] #(100,1)
                        #print(np.shape(y))
                        #In 2
                        #%% ==================== Part 1: Plotting ====================
                        postive_value = data.loc[data[2] == 1]
                        #print(postive_value.values[:,2:3])
                        negative_value = data.loc[data[2] == 0]
                        #print(len(postive_value))
                        #print(len(negative_value))
                        ax1 = postive_value.plot(kind='scatter',x=0,y=1,s=50,color='b',marker="+",label="Admitted") # S is line width #https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter 
                        ax2 = negative_value.plot(kind='scatter',x=0,y=1,s=50,color='y',ax=ax1,label="Not Admitted")
                        ax1.set_xlabel("Exam 1 score")
                        ax2.set_ylabel("Exam 2 score")
                        plt.show()
                        #print(ax1 == ax2)
                        #print(np.shape(X))

                # In 3
                        #============ Part 2: Compute Cost and Gradient ===========
                        [m,n] = np.shape(X) #(100,2)
                        print(m,n)
                        additional_coulmn = np.ones((m,1))
                        X = np.append(additional_coulmn,X,axis=1)
                        initial_theta = np.zeros((n+1), dtype=int)
                        print(initial_theta)

                        # In4
                        #Sigmoid and cost function
                        def sigmoid(z):
                            g = np.zeros(np.shape(z));
                            g = 1/(1+np.exp(-z));
                            return g
                        def costFunction(theta, X, y):
                               J = 0;
                               #print(theta)
                               receive_theta = np.array(theta)[np.newaxis] ##This command is used to create the 1D array 
                               #print(receive_theta)
                               theta = np.transpose(receive_theta)
                               #print(np.shape(theta))       
                               #grad = np.zeros(np.shape(theta))
                               z = np.dot(X,theta) # where z = theta*X
                               #print(z)
                               h = sigmoid(z) #formula h(x) = g(z) whether g = 1/1+e(-z) #(100,1)
                               #print(np.shape(h))
                               #J = np.sum(((-y)*np.log(h)-(1-y)*np.log(1-h))/m); 
                               J = np.sum(np.dot((-y.T),np.log(h))-np.dot((1-y).T,np.log(1-h)))/m
                               #J = (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()
                               #error = h-y
                               #print(np.shape(error))
                               #print(np.shape(X))
                               grad =np.dot(X.T,(h-y))/m
                               #print(grad)
                               return J,grad
            #In5
                        [cost, grad] = costFunction(initial_theta, X, y)
                        print('Cost at initial theta (zeros):', cost)
                        print('Expected cost (approx): 0.693\n')
                        print('Gradient at initial theta (zeros): \n',grad)
                        print('Expected gradients (approx):\n -0.1000\n -12.0092\n -11.2628\n')

            In6 # Compute and display cost and gradient with non-zero theta
            test_theta = [-24, 0.2, 0.2]
            #test_theta_value = np.array([-24, 0.2, 0.2])[np.newaxis]  #This command is used to create the 1D row array 

            #test_theta = np.transpose(test_theta_value) # Transpose 
            #test_theta = test_theta_value.transpose()
            [cost, grad] = costFunction(test_theta, X, y)

            print('\nCost at test theta: \n', cost)
            print('Expected cost (approx): 0.218\n')
            print('Gradient at test theta: \n',grad);
            print('Expected gradients (approx):\n 0.043\n 2.566\n 2.647\n')


        #IN6
    # ============= Part 3: Optimizing using range  =============
    import scipy.optimize as opt
    #initial_theta_initialize = np.array([0, 0, 0])[np.newaxis]
    #initial_theta = np.transpose(initial_theta_initialize)
    print ('Executing minimize function...\n')
    # Working models
    #result = opt.minimize(costFunction,initial_theta,args=(X,y),method='TNC',jac=True,options={'maxiter':400})
    result = opt.fmin_tnc(func=costFunction, x0=initial_theta, args=(X, y))
    # Not working model
    #costFunction(initial_theta,X,y)
    #model = opt.minimize(fun = costFunction, x0 = initial_theta, args = (X, y), method = 'TNC',jac = costFunction)
    print('Thetas found by fmin_tnc function: ', result);
    print('Cost at theta found : \n', cost);
    print('Expected cost (approx): 0.203\n');
    print('theta: \n',result[0]);
    print('Expected theta (approx):\n');
    print(' -25.161\n 0.206\n 0.201\n');
```

Result:
Executing minimize function...

Thetas found by fmin_tnc function:  (array([-25.16131854,   0.20623159,   0.20147149]), 36, 0)
Cost at theta found : 
 0.218330193827
Expected cost (approx): 0.203

theta: 
 [-25.16131854   0.20623159   0.20147149]
Expected theta (approx):

-25.161
 0.206
 0.201

Answer (score 0):

> scipy’s fmin_tnc doesn’t work well with column or row vector. It expects the parameters to be in an array format.

[Python Implementation of Andrew Ng’s Machine Learning Course (Part 2.1)](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/python-implementation-of-andrew-ngs-machine-learning-course-part-2-1-1a666f049ad6?spm=a2c4e.11153940.blogcont638717.13.74875c35nLwQWy)

```
opt.fmin_tnc(func = costFunction, x0 = theta.flatten(),fprime = gradient, args = (X, y.flatten()))
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to reshape y as a vector (1-D) rather than a matrix (2-D array). I simply used the following code and then reran the SciPy's minimize function and it worked.

y = np.reshape(y,100) #e.g., if your y variable has 100 data points.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late but I also started anderw assignment to implement with Python and put a lot of effort to resolve the mentioned issue. Finally is works for me.

This [blog](https://www.johnwittenauer.net/machine-learning-exercises-in-python-part-3/) help me but with one changes in **fmin_tnc** function calling, refer below :-

`result = op.fmin_tnc(func=costFunction, x0=initial_theta, fprime=None, approx_grad=True, args=(X, y))` Got this info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836455/scipy-fmin-tnc-not-optimizing-cost-function?rq=1)